# Check AWS Appsync is connected to the endpoint socket

Tags: aws-appsync, aws-amplify

I am using AWS appsync for chat app. Is there any way be sure that Appsync is connected to the end point socket before sending request? Like `onConnect` socket event.

Comment: If you create a GraphQL subscription with AppSync then when your callback runs it's equivalent to an `onConnect` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AppSync SDK doesn't maintain an active connection to the endpoint. However, when you subscribe to an object, the SDK creates a WebSocket connection for Subscriptions with GraphQL. If you use AppSync subscriptions and subscribe on an object, the SDK opens a WebSocket connection and keeps the connection alive until the connection is lost due to network failures. This connection makes sure you get the relevant updates on the object you have been subscribed to.

Documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/building-a-client-app-android.html#subscriptions

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/building-a-client-app-ios.html#subscriptions